# Download Word .docx as Blob file from Angular on mobile devices

Tags: android, angular, blob, docx, filesaver.js

I am trying to download .docx file from REST API (.NET Core [FileContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1)) in Angular application. Everything is working fine on PC, but there is problem with downloading .docx files in VMware Workspace ONE Web browser (didn't try standard browsers like Chrome or Safari, it looks like there is just Android WebView). It is company application and this browser is the only one allowed.

**The problem is only with .docx files. Files like PDF, .doc and .xlsx (created by [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)) are working fine.**

**REST API call** (also tried with 'arraybuffer' instead of 'blob' and created Blob object in client, but problem persists)

```
this.httpClient.get(requestUrl, {
  responseType: 'blob',
  observe: 'response'
});
```

Then I save response body with [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

```
generateDocument(file: string | Blob, name: string): void {
  FileSaver.saveAs(file, name);
}
```

- I also tried approach that creates link and click on it (it does not work).
- Solution with using window.open(blobUrl) is not working.

**EDIT:**

- I got information that it is not working at all in iOS with same browser. Users get error message "*Link is invalid.*"

Can someone help me with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a test file available that's not working properly? Testing on Android or IOS?

Comment: I also tested simple .docx file created in MS Word (Microsoft 365) with text "Test" inside. I am testing on Android. It tries to open the document in Microsoft Word on mobile phone, but Word says that file is corrupted and if I try to use fix there, I get only error message "File cannot be opened".

Comment: I made a test file for you: https://batman.dev/static/70085191/download.docx

Comment: I also created test page with different solutions and they are all working fine in browsers like Chrome and Safari, but not in VMware Workspace ONE Web browser. The problem is browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you can retrieve obtain an `ArrayBuffer`, this could be used to initiate the download with those bytes:

Test here: https://batman.dev/static/70085191/

```
async function downloadUrl(url) {
  downloadBuffer(
    await (await fetch(url)).arrayBuffer()
  )
}

function downloadBuffer(arrayBuffer) {
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(
    [ arrayBuffer ],
    { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' }
  ))
  a.download = 'my-file.docx'
  a.click()
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Mobile phone couldn't open the document.

Comment: Try the working test I added. It downloaded and opened on my Android Chrome phone.

Comment: It works fine in Chrome, but not in VMware Workspace ONE Web. I made test page with different solutions and tested in Chrome on Android and Safari on iOS. Everything is working fine in these browsers.